# how to upload file in appium for mobile app automation?

Tags: selenium, appium, perfecto

I am trying to automate the file upload functionality for mobile application automation. I have some pdf/image file stored in my mobile device which is need to be uploaded. What will be the possible way to automate this scenario?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: used the sendkeys(file location) method but it is throwing exception .

Comment: Could you please update the question with the relevant code and details, it will help us to help you :)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is no way to repeat Selenium javascript trick with `sendKeys` with native mobile application:

you need literally *do everything via UI* - open image selection, select image and etc.

The only thing that Appium can assist with is to [upload files to device](https://appium.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/commands/device/files/push-file/), so your device can be cleaned and populated only during the test.